# Refer to HTML element from directive angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm doing some DOM manipulation by adding function on click event inside my directive.

Basically it's animation of moving 4 little boxes to right and showing 4 "new" boxes sliding from left side. For real that's just 20 boxes in line with hidden overflow that you can see only 4 at time and on click it's just adding `margin-left: -270px` to pretend horizontal scrolling.

Currently I'm "catching" this 20 elements with

`document.querySelectorAll(".last-added-element").forEach(function(elem) {`

and this solution is working fine untill I use my directive twice at same page (same view). It's then scrolling boxes in both direcrives when I execute function.

Can I somehow scope above line (`querySelectorAll` method) to get NodeList of results but only from its template no entire DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link` in directive exposes element the directive is called on so query from that element

```
link:function(scope, element, attrs){
   // element is a jQlite object
   element[0].querySelector('.someClass').doSomething 
}
```

Comment: but it's `restrict: 'E',` directive it's not called on some html element it's more like component: `<horizontal-elements></horizontal-elements>`.

Comment: doesn't make any difference. Th `<horizontal-elements>` element is still `element` in `link` arguments

Comment: You could add that I can't use `getElementById` with `el[0]` only `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`. :D But anyay this answer is efficient, thanks!